# after generated .exe using pyinstaller it give me error (no module named exchangelib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyinstaller, exchangelib

I am writing python code to fetch inbox mails using credentials and I am using exchangelib and importing some modules but when I generate .exe file using pyinstaller it give me this error after run the .exe file (ModuleNotFoundError : No module named 'exchangelib')

I tried to solve it by change hidden imports in .spec file but it failed .

here is my impot libraries

```
from exchangelib import Account , Credentials , Configuration
from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
```

Comment: OK Guys I figured it out :
first explicitly import libraary before from in .py:
then generate EXE by this line :
(pyinstaller.exe  --onefile -w script_name.py)
but write it in the terminal in Pycharm not in command window in the project folder ..

here is my impot libraries :
   `import exchangelib`

   `from exchangelib import Account , Credentials , Configuration`

   `from exchangelib.protocol import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK Guys I figured it out : first explicitly import libraary before from in .py: then generate EXE by this line : (pyinstaller.exe --onefile -w script_name.py) but write it in the terminal in Pycharm not in command window in the project folder .. 
here is my impot libraries :

```
import exchangelib from exchangelib 
import Account , Credentials , Configuration from exchangelib.protocol 
import BaseProtocol, NoVerifyHTTPAdapter
```